# dynamically growing rows and columns of 2D Array

Tags: c++

101 175 123 52 78 184 202 8 219 15 49 254 86 62

156 213 41 200 123 131 252 186 108 116 39 205 243 120

218 239 201 109 52 173 244 58 185 18 64 209 165 222

81 136 247 149 183 206 164 214  179 121 176 200 89 128

61 224 221 103 114 170 88 133 117 30 104 46 19 151

99 111 41 180 188 1 32 27 100 241 97 56 22 10

So I have my school project. I need to read integers from a file and allocate dynamic memory and store those integers. The array rows and columns are growing dynamically as needed. The code is working fine step by step  but if I try to randomly access an index of the array, it gives me an erroe. Please help me out

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int* grow(int* ptr,int& cols, int num);
int** grow(int** ptr,int& size);
int main()
{
   int num=0; 
   int cols=0;
   int size=0;
   int** mat=nullptr;
   int* ptr=nullptr;
   ifstream fin;
   fin.open("numbers.txt");
   string line;
   while (getline(fin, line))
   {
      mat=grow(mat,size);

      for(int i=0; i<line.size(); i++)
      {
         num=0;
         while(line[i]!=' ' && line[i]!='\n')
         {
            num=(num*10)+line[i]-'0';
            i++;

         }
         mat[size]=grow(mat[size],cols,num);


      }
        cout<<"Size:"<<size<<endl;
        for(int i=0; i<cols; i++)
        {

            cout<<mat[size][i]<<' ';       // working fine
        }
        cout<<endl;
      cols=0;

   }
   cout<<endl<<endl<<mat[2][4]<<endl;  //not working

}
int** grow(int** mat,int& size)
{
   int** ptr=new int*[size+1];
   for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
   {
      ptr[i]=mat[i];
   }
   size++;
   return ptr;
}
int* grow(int* ptr,int& cols, int num)
{
   int* nptr=new int[cols+1];
   for(int i=0; i<cols; i++)
   {
      nptr[i]=ptr[i];
   }
   nptr[cols++]=num;

   return nptr;
}
```

Comment: The code you show is C++ not C.

Comment: As for your problem, it seems that each line you read will have 14 numbers. If that's so you can simplify the code by having a dynamic array of `int[14]`.

Comment: School project – so again another one where not allowed to use `std::vector`? If no such restriction, you absolutely should prefer...

Comment: but  I am supposed to make code super generic so that  it can handle any number of rows or columns

Comment: @Aconcagua we aren't taught that yet

Comment: and are you allowed to use it? `std::vector` is easy to learn. Working with `int**` is more like juggling with scissors, ie not very beginner-friendly, perhaps thats a reason it is often used to scare beginners, a strategy not everybody (including me) fully supports. Just be aware that you are not learning to write nice C++ when you are not allowed to use `std::vector`

Comment: You need to `delete[]` the previous pointers, otherwise you are leeking a lot of memory. `<mat[2][4]<<endl;  //not working` - so  what is the value of `cols` and `rows` at this moment? `mat[size]=` is out of bound access, I think this is your error. The array has `size` elements - that means last element is at `mat[size - 1]`. As to ` //not working` - what does it mean "not working"? How do you detect it "does not work"? Please be specific. `gives me an erroe` - please fix the spelling. What error? Please post the exact error message.

Comment: Are you sure you would have a separate single column (`ptr`)? Wouldn't you rather have a complete row stored in each pointer of `matrix`, and all the same indices in each such row form a column on their own?